# Шаблонная (или нет) функция, которую можно вызвать только один раз

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужна идея, как реализовать такое: Есть шаблонная функция, которая регистрирует тип при запуске программы. Хочется сделать так, чтоб если мы в двух разных местах программы пытаемся зарезистрировать один и тот же тип, то сборка ломается. Сейчас такая проверка происходит в момент запуска.
Примерное использование в коде такое:

```
// Module1.cpp
void Module1::initModule()
{
   ...
   registerType<AAA>(Factory1());
   registerType<BBB>([this]() { return this->createBBB();});
   ...
}

// Module2.cpp
void Module2::initModule()
{
   ...
   registerType<CCC>([]() { return CCCImpl(); });
   registerType<AAA>(Factory2()); // <- Вот тут на линковке(?) должно сломаться
   ...
}
```

**UPD:** Уточнение. Типы AAA, BBB, CCC это интерфейсы и определены заранее и не обязательно в том модуле где вызывается регистрация. В момент регистрации registerType(...) мы по факту передаем правильно сконфигурированную фабрику.

Comment: К сожалению, такое решение не спасет Вас от перерегистрации, допустим в подключаемой библиотеке. Так что, на мой взгляд, лучше делать проверку еще и в рантайме, как это делается в Qt

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы "сломалось" на линковке нужно создать в модуле extern (и не weak) символ.

К сожалению, сделать это внутри функции не получится (точнее, я не знаю, как это сделать).

Наверное, проще всего объявить о своих намерениях вне функции, используя макрос, который раскроется в код функции.

Она может реально ниоткуда и не вызываться, хотя для контроля целостности можно (например, тоже макросом) сгенерить код, вызывающий эту функцию внутри вашей `registerType<>`.

Макрос может быть примерно таким:

```
#define USE_REGISTER(name) const char * f_ ## name () { return #name; }
```

Вы вставляете его в свой файл по одному разу для каждого регистрируемого где-то далее типа.

Comment: типа шаблонный  class Singleton?..

Comment: Зачем `extern`? Если функция не объявлена как `static`, она во время компоновки так же будет видна по всей программе, благодаря чему компоновка и «ломается» на множественных объявлениях.

Comment: @Arhad, как известно, если нет слова `static`, значит `extern` (а где в коде вы увидели чтобы я его написал?)

Comment: @avp, но `extern` — это же объявление сущности, реализованной в какой-то другой единице компиляции, разве нет?

Comment: @Arhad, ключевое слово `extern` в языке -- да, используется именно в этом смысле. А вообще, все глобальные объекты на сленге зовут екстернами. Я именно в этом смысле -- что надо сделать глобальный (в смысле линкера) и не weak объект.

Comment: @avp Думал об этом, вмомент вызова initModule есть дополнительная информация, которая нужна. Мой вариант был такой же, только не `return #name`, а registerType<name>(...), а в `initModule` вызов `f_AAA(...)`, но эстетика страдает.

Comment: @ffk, когда я вижу все эти крестовые нагромождения букв мне грустно становится... О какой эстетике тут вообще можно говорить?